# Having to use deprecated classes with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Have been trial Spring Web MVC (4.2.5) and have his a number of issues trying to use a DispatcherServlet and

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Have setup a simple @Controller class and wanted to use the POJO to JSON mapping.  The docu said that if Jackson was detected on the class path it would be used automatically, however this didn't work for me and I was forced to use the 'deprecated' AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter

```
<bean name="mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" >
  <property name="messageConverters" ref="mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
</bean>
```

which then worked fine.

Equally, tried to create a @ControllerAdvice class for handling all exceptions, but only got an @ExceptionHandler method working on the same controller class, and that was only when I added the (again) deprecated AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver to the context.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver" />
```

Having to instantiate two deprecated classes suggests I am doing something wrong, especially when all the tutorials seem to suggest this should all 'just work', but I cannot see what (and indeed nosing through the Spring source I cannot see how the default and recommended handlers would work anyway)

There are no errors, the annotation simply aren't detected.  The fill context xml is

please find the entire context XML below (is very simple)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>

<bean name="mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" >
    <property name="messageConverters" ref="mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.domain.datastore.dao"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.domain.service"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.domain.uiapi"/>

</beans>
```

An example controller is

```
@RestController("/place/*")
public class PlaceController {

private PlaceService placeService;

@Autowired
public PlaceController(PlaceService placeService) {
    this.placeService = placeService;
}

@RequestMapping(path="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Place getPlace(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model)   {
    return placeService.getPlace(id);
}


}
```

and the cross-cutting exception handler is

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionController {

public GlobalExceptionController() {
    System.out.println("GlobalExceptionController");
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
public ModelAndView handleCustomException(NotFoundException ex) {
    return  null;
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the error logs

Comment: Can you elaborate on what didn't work?  Did you receive an error message?  Did the application start up or not?

Comment: It would be little bit more clear, if you would provide full code of your xml configuration.

Comment: Include the configuration... and how you are loading things. If you add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to the root context it might fail for the servlet (at least partially as it might not be detected properly). Also how does your controller look?

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter was replaced by org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver was replaced by ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver

Comment: @bnrdo  There aren't any error logs, the handlers simply don't 'detect' the annotations.

Comment: @M.Deinum, regarding the annotation-driven not being detected, how can that be addressed?

Comment: @ekemchitsiga When stepping through the Spring code I can see that the ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver is instantiated but when it 'examines' my controller it doesn't seem to looks for the annotations, where as the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter does.

Comment: If you're "trying Spring out", use Spring Boot. It handles all of the usual configuration automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that Spring MVC was matching the path in

```
@RestController("/place/*")
```

And as such passing the instance of PlaceController around as the handler.  The ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver expects a HandlerMethod and so was unable to process the exception.

As such dropping the path from the class annotation and putting the full path in the method got it all working and I dropped all the deprecated beans.

```
@RestController
public class PlaceController {

@RequestMapping(path="/place/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Place getPlace(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model)
```

What I am not sure is if this is a bug.  Shouldn't it be possible to put the 'base' path in the RestController annotation and the subpath in the RequestMapping?

Comment: value of `@RestController` is not the path, it's a component name. If you want to put the path on class level use `@RequestMapping` on the type.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you don't want to use a deprecated class. `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is indeed Deprecated. As doc suggest you should use `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` instead.

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html) for the details.

And instead of `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` you can use `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`.

Comment: If you look at the source of the ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver you will see it stores the class labelled with the ControllerAdvice annotation in the exceptionHandlerAdviceCache variable, but then completely ignores it in shouldApplyTo when determining if it can handle the exception.  I cannot see how ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver actually supports ControllerAdvice annotation

Comment: @Matt maybe your `@ControllerAdvice` class is not being picked by the component-scan? what package is it in?

Comment: @Matt One thing to note is that having `<mvc:annotation-driven>` should result in `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` being created by default. No need to specify it manually.